# Dropdown onchange using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, onchange, dropdown

I have a dropdown in my form which I used to filter data. I am using ajax onchange function to filter the data based on the selected list.

My dropdown looked something like this :

```
<select id="opt_level" name="opt_level">
    <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
    <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
    <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
</select>
```

And here is the div that I wanted to display the onchange data :

```
<div id="opt_lesson_list">
    <!-- Some statement here -->
</div>
```

When there is onchange on dropdown, it will go through this ajax function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#opt_level").on('change', function() {
        var level = $(this).val();
        if(level){
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example-domain.com',
                data: { hps_level: '' + level + '' },
                success : function(htmlresponse) {
                    $('#opt_lesson_list').html(htmlresponse);
                    console.log(htmlresponse);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And going to the url `example-domain.com` to check if there is post made from ajax :

```
if(isset($_POST['hps_level'])){
    // Statement to select from database
}
```

So after filtering done, data inside the `<div id="opt_lesson_list"></div>` should display the filtered data. But what happened is, the `ajax` response to the whole page which means that my whole form is multiplying and displayed in the div that I used to display onchange data.

**EDIT**

My PHP is just filtering data from database based on the value selected :

```
if(isset($_POST['hps_level'])){
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(hps_lessons) FROM holiday_program_setup WHERE hps_level = '".$_POST['hps_level']."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<ul class="list-unstyled subjects">';
            echo '<li class="bordered" style="width: 30%;">';
            echo $row['hps_lessons'];
            echo '</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
    $sql = NULL;
}
```

If I `echo $_POST['hps_level'];` I can get the value of the dropdown selected.

Comment: What's the server side get ? and what it try to send back

Comment: is this all on one file? If so, make 2 files: one that displays, one that receives and answeres the ajax request. _OR_ exclude the html to be displayed _if_ you have a `$_POST['hps_level']`

Comment: @WallSkyBlue it sending back the whole html page

Comment: Actually, it seems like server-side issue. Can you share your server (PHP) code?

Comment: so it has nothing to do with ajax, fix your php (which you didn't provide)

Comment: Yes, you've got to use at least two PHP files, one for only the content of `<div id="opt_lesson_list">` and another for the main page containing `<div id="opt_lesson_list">`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I created a custom page template in a wordpress so it a bit hard for me to separate the php page and html page. Since I am really new to wordpress so I feel it easy for me to do in the same page.

Comment: @Emerald: Oh, new information. I don't do Wordpress, sorry.

Comment: Your endpoint in "url:" must be able to provide just the information that need to fit in `<div id="opt_lesson_list">` , response with whole page is out of question

Comment: Well, actually there is, like specify dataType as "html" and parse whole page response but that's too ugly to recommend

Comment: Your AJAX requests the content from example-domain.com; that content seems to be your complete page including the form. You need to query a URL that just sends the data that should be presented within `opt_lesson_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my whole form is multiplying and displayed in the div that I used to
>   display onchange data.

It seems like you are pointing your ajax url `example-domain.com` to the page where all your html page is and the ajax returning the whole html page to your div response `<div id="opt_lesson_list"></div>`.

Try to create another blank php page and put your php `isset` code in the new php file.

```
if(isset($_POST['hps_level'])){
    // Statement to select from database
}
```

Replace your `ajax url` with the new php file url. By doing that, your ajax will grab all the data from the new file and display in your response div.

Answer (score 0):

your provide valid url,becz data filter to hps_level

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#opt_level").on('change', function() {
        var level = $(this).val();
        alert(level);
        if(level){
               $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example-domain.com',
                data: { hps_level: '' + level + '' },
                success : function(htmlresponse) {
                    $('#opt_lesson_list').append(htmlresponse);
                    alert(htmlresponse);
                },error:function(e){
                alert("error");}
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="opt_level" name="opt_level">
    <option value="level1">Level 1</option>
    <option value="level2">Level 2</option>
    <option value="level3">Level 3</option>
</select>

<div id="opt_lesson_list">
    <!-- Some statement here -->
</div>
```